# is there any way to refactor this code and avoid the use of all multiples if statement?

Tags: typescript, if-statement, switch-statement, refactoring

I am trying to refactor this code to avoid the use of so many if statements, any suggestions you can give me? . The problem is that I have 4 different inputs to give a single answer.

```html
const alert= markers.some((marker) => marker['hasAlerts'] > 0);
const warning= markers.some((marker) => marker['hasWarnings'] > 0);
const isCurrentHourAlert = markers.some((marker) => marker['isCurrentHourAlert'] > 0);
const isCurrentHourWarnings = markers.some((marker) => marker['isCurrentHourWarnings'] > 0);

        let style = 0;

        if (isCurrentHourAlert && isCurrentHourWarnings) {
            style = 4;
        } else if (isCurrentHourAlert) {
            style = 4;
        } else if (isCurrentHourWarnings) {
            style = 5;
        } else if (alert && warning) {
            style = 2;
        } else if (alert) {
            style = 2;
        } else if (warning) {
            style = 3;
        } else {
            style = 1;
        }
```

I tried converting this to a switch case statement, but it's still code with a lot of validation.

I would like to know if I can apply some pattern or other structure that is easier to read and to refactor the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function that iterates over the markers and checks for the property you're interested in would help some.

You run `style = 4;` regardless if `isCurrentHourAlert` is true, so you can eliminate the first branch entirely.

```
const markersHas = prop => markers.some(marker => marker[prop] > 0);
let style = 0;
if (markersHas('isCurrentHourAlert')) {
    style = 4;
} else if (markersHas('isCurrentHourWarnings')) {
    style = 5;
}
// etc
```

If you want to use `switch`, it'd look like

```
switch (true) {
  case markersHas('isCurrentHourAlert'):
    style = 4;
    break;
  case markersHas('isCurrentHourWarnings'):
    style = 5;
    break;
  // etc
```

Another option is to use an array of conditions / style pairs, then iterate through the array to find the first truthy condition, and use its associated style.

```
const styleConds = [
    [markersHas('isCurrentHourAlert'), 4],
    [markersHas('isCurrentHourWarnings'), 5],
    // etc
];
const styleCond = styleConds.find(cond => cond[0]);
const style = styleCond?.[1] ?? 0;
```

From a higher level perspective, you also might consider if there's a way to avoid these sorts of magic numbers entirely - better to use something more informative if at all possible. (for example, a line like `style = 4;` doesn't make all that much sense at a glance - what does 4 mean?)